# response.end() send error

Tags: asp.net, xml, jquery

Script

```
$.ajax({
type: "post",
url: "Index.aspx?cmd=SettingCreateMember",
success: parseXml
});
```

Code
in MasterPage_pagrLoad()

```
if (Request["cmd"] == "SettingCreateMember")
        {
            var doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath(".") + "\\Administrator\\Questions.config");
            Response.Write(doc);
            Response.End();  //this line error:Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack
}
```

inline response.end() error say:Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack
why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exception when download file in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291180/exception-when-download-file-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response.End uses a ThreadAbortException to end execution of the page and flush the buffer to the client ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end.aspx)). Response.Flush() will not generate a ThreadAbortException.